# MySQL5 Query Help to find non-validating rows of join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Find below the test tables:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_emp; // There must be few employee with no dept id (did)
+------+-------+------+
| eid  | ename | did  |
+------+-------+------+
|    1 | SCOTT |    2 |
|    2 | JAMES |    4 |
|    3 | BOND  |    1 |
|    4 | TIGER |    5 |
|    5 | CHIP  |    0 |
|    6 | DALE  |    0 |
|    7 | MARY  |    0 |
+------+-------+------+

SELECT * FROM tbl_dept;// There must be few depts which have no employee.
+-------+-------------+
| dptid | dname       |
+-------+-------------+
|     1 | HR          |
|     2 | IT          |
|     3 | ADMIN       |
|     4 | TRAVEL      |
|     5 | SALES       |
|     6 | FINANCE     |
|     7 | ENGINEERING |
+-------+-------------+
```

I want to list all the employee name from tbl_emp which does not have dept and all the dname from tbl_dept which have no employee in a SINGLE QUERY in following manner:

```
DESIRED RESULTSET:
-------------------
ename  dname
CHIP    
DALE
MARY
       ADMIN
       FINANCE
       ENGINEERING
-------------------
```

All I could do is:

```
SELECT ename FROM tbl_emp WHERE did NOT IN (SELECT dptid FROM tbl_dept);
```

and

```
SELECT dname FROM tbl_dept WHERE dptid NOT IN (SELECT did FROM tbl_emp);
```

Please help in select both dname and ename and that too in single query.

Comment: Note that you could do this with a full outer join, but mysql does not support full outer joins.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `UNION`

```
SELECT ename, NULL dname 
FROM tbl_emp 
WHERE did NOT IN (SELECT dptid FROM tbl_dept)
UNION
SELECT NULL ename, dname 
FROM tbl_dept 
WHERE dptid NOT IN (SELECT did FROM tbl_emp);
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6247a/1)

**UPDATE 1**

you can also use `LEFT JOIN` instead of using `NOT IN` (*I'd rather use this one*)

```
SELECT  a.ename, b.dname 
FROM    tbl_emp a 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_dept b
            ON a.did = b.dptid
WHERE   b.dptid IS NULL
UNION
SELECT  c.ename, d.dname 
FROM    tbl_dept d 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_emp c
            ON d.dptid = c.did
WHERE   c.did IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6247a/4)